# Merged other branch to my branch and pushed too many commits to remote

Tags: git

I have a branch A which only I'm working on that.
I also have a branch B where lots of other people are working on that.
I merged branch B into branch A then made changes in branch A.
Committed and pushed to my remote branch A
But when I check the remote repo, I found I also committed 1000+ commits from other people to my remote branch A.

Is there a simple way I can revert that push to remote branch A?

Comment: This is how merge works - you've incorporated all the changes done in branch B to yours. Try to reset local branch A, and push it back to remote. But overall, maybe `git flow` model could be interested for you, in order to organize work using git.

Comment: You could use `--no-ff` (no fast forward) when merging to sum up the changes in other branch into a single "merge commit".

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to rebase all commits with a single commit, thus removing history of other developer's commits.

Let's say commits are as follows:

```
latest_commit
a
b
c
.
.
.
after_merge
your_last_commit
```

Run the following scripts:

```
git checkout <your_branch>
git rebase -i your_last_commit
```

When prompted to input add `after_merge..latest_commit` and so these commits will be deleted at local history. When you push those changes it will be a non fast forward update.

**Disclaimer:** Although it achieves the required behavior but it may cause issues with collaborations. Read more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) (**Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository and that people may have based work on**).